# Which user data can be stored in my system apart from the Facebook ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I would like to know if I can store more data than a Facebook user id. In the old API it says no.

From ttp://developers.facebook.com/docs/ref … ndardinfo/:

> The only storable values returned from this call are the user IDs.

But, could I store data if I do not relate it to the user? For instance: If the user is a woman, and rates something in my page, could I count a +1 women vote in my page without relating to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That information is really old. Long ago Facebook changed the rules so you could "cache" any information 24 hours. Last year they then changed it so you could store it indefinitely. However, there are still rules on what that information can be used for. Look at the question "How long can I store data?" http://www.facebook.com/help/new/?page=1100

Now it's pretty much all based around permissions. Basic authorization gets you basic information about the user, based on their privacy settings. The user may not allow you to tell their gender. If you want more information, you need to prompt the user to grant you access to that additional information. Facebook has even setup a real time API for subscribing to user information changes. For example, you can get "alerted" if a user changes their gender (bad example).